# Cleaning up this conditional within a Java Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this long Java stream, but threw a conditional in here that looks out of place:

```
...
    .filter(desc -> !hiddenFields.contains(desc.getName()))
    .forEach(
        desc -> {
          if (requestedFields.isEmpty()
              || requestedFields.contains(desc.getName())) {
            allAttributes.add(desc);
          }
        }));
```

requestedFields is a `HashSet<String>`. Is there anything prettier?

Comment: @Ele Sorry, tags from a different question in draft was cached. Updated.

Comment: Put the conditional in the `filter`? Add more `filter`(s). Why do an `if` in the `forEach`?

Comment: Ok ok Good :-)...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm not quite sure how to do it with the isEmpty() check. Can the conditional just be moved 1:1 to a new filter?

Comment: What is `allAttributes`? If it is a `List` and empty before that code, then you should use `collect(Collectors.toList)` instead of `forEach(...)`

Comment: @RyanHack Why don't you try moving it to a `filter(...)` and see what happens?

Comment: @Andreas It's a set of a special type

Comment: I just added an extra filter, moved the conditional into the filter and added the .add statement in the foreach by itself. Seems good

Comment: So `collect(Collectors.toCollection(MySpecialSet::new))`

Comment: I return from this function a set of that special type. I'm trying to understand what I gain from putting it into a collection

Comment: @Ryan A set, whether it's your special set or `HashSet` is always a `Collection`, so you can use `Collectors.toCollection(YourSet::new)`

Answer (score 2):

```
allAttributes = stream.filter(desc -> !hiddenFields.contains(desc.getName()))
.filter(desc -> requestedFields.isEmpty()
          || requestedFields.contains(desc.getName()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as pointed out in the comments of the question, you can use `Collectors.toCollection(...)` instead of `.toList()` depending of the type of `allAttributes`